# Why this filter hook is not working when passing parameters?

Tags: filters

Supposing I have this function which I hooked into my_get_users function:

```
function define_users($group) {

//Query database for users belonging to a group
global $wpdb;

$users= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='groupname' AND meta_value=$group",ARRAY_N);

return $users;

}

add_filter('my_get_users','define_users',10,1);
```

This is my_get_users function where the apply_filters are found:

```
function my_get_users($group) {

//Define users as array
$users=array();     


$users = apply_filters('my_get_users', $users, $group);


    return $users;

}
```

I am sure there is data in the database but the $users variable is returning as an empty array. Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**$users = apply_filters('my_get_users',$group);**

Comment: @Jesse nice answer, but please try to explain what went wrong to help answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few mistakes here, but your general direction is the right one.

Your line

```
apply_filters('my_get_users', $users, $group);
```

Implies that 2 Parameters are passed on to your function `my_get_users`. You pass $users as an empty array, which is not necessary, but your main problem here is another one.

You hook into your filter by

```
add_filter('my_get_users','define_users',10,1);
```

This line tells WordPress that your function `define_users` accepts 1 parameter (the value of the 4th parameter in this line).

So WordPress tries to pass 2 Parameters:

- $users (an empty array)
- $group

As your function is set to only accept one paremter, it just gets the empty `$users` array.

In your function `define_users($group)` $group gets the value of your previous $users, and so your Query will not return a correct result, as you use `$group` in there.

The solutions would be (two possibilities):

#### Pass just one Parameter to your Filter

```
function define_users($group) {

    //Query database for users belonging to a group
    global $wpdb;

    $users= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='groupname' AND meta_value=$group",ARRAY_N);

    return $users;

}

add_filter('my_get_users','define_users',10,1);

function my_get_users($group) {

    $users = apply_filters('my_get_users', $group);

    return $users;

}
```

#### Define your function for 2 Parameters (not used in this case)

```
function define_users($users, $group) {

    //Query database for users belonging to a group
    global $wpdb;

    $users= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='groupname' AND meta_value=$group",ARRAY_N);

    return $users;

}

add_filter('my_get_users','define_users',10,2);

function my_get_users($group) {

    //Define users as array
    $users=array();     

    $users = apply_filters('my_get_users', $users, $group);

    return $users;

}
```

### What else to say

- Please check the following things: Do you really need to place a manual query or could this be done by `get_users`?
- In this case there is actually no need for a filter, unless you have other functions with a hook for altering your userlist.